# Eliminating unwanted rows in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table of employee training records showing courses attended (recorded as 'Finished'), and courses enrolled on. Frequently, employees will be enrolled again on a course they 'Finished' years ago. So two rows exist - one for Finished, and one for Enrolled.

Where these scenarios occur - I only want to show the 'Enrolled' row.

The data is structured like this:

[image]

If it helps - the `Course_Start_Date` for `Finished` courses is always older than `Enrolled` start dates.

Any ideas on how I can remove these rows when they occur please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to eliminate courses where the same person is currently enrolled on the same course.

```
SELECT  En, Last_Name, FirstName, Course, Course_start_Date, Enrollment_Status
FROM    T
WHERE   Enrollment_Status = 'Enrolled'
OR      NOT EXISTS 
        (   SELECT  1 
            FROM    T AS T2 
            WHERE   T2.En = T.En
            AND     T2.Course = T.Course
            AND     T2.Enrollment_Status = 'Enrolled'
        );
```

Comment: OMG - that's perfect.  Thank you so much. Thanks for such a quick reply too.